# Return from async function

Tags: javascript, promise

I wonder if it is mandatory to return from an async function, for example:

```
async function foo() {
  return bar(); // bar returns a promise
}
```

or can I just do

```
async function foo() {
  bar();
}
```

because async will automatically return a promise but should I return the original promise and not a new one auto-created by async?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

An async function is guaranteed to return Promise, but when that Promise settles and what it delivers are determined by what the function returns.

Comment: And for example if `bar` returns a Promise<void>, is it the same to return or not return it?

Comment: No, similar as a normal function, if nothing is explicitly returned, then an async function will return Promise<undefined>.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you want a value to be passed to the next promise in the chain. It is normally a good practice to return a value to the promise unless it is the last function in the chain, or there isn't information to pass on (for some reason).

If the only reason `bar()` is being called is because it causes some side-effect outside the function (changes a global var, updates a DB, etc) I suppose you could not return. But even then I still would return some value for success, especially if `bar()` performed I/O.

```
function bar(){
  return 'hello world';
}

async function foo1() {
  bar(); // Returns a promise with an empty value
}

async function foo2() {
  return bar(); // returns a promise with the _value_ returned from bar()
}

foo1().then(console.log); // undefined
foo2().then(console.log); // 'Hello World'
```